# PHP while loop with individual MySQL Select queries - how to speed up?

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have a web page which displays 50 rows from a database, and there's a "Refresh All" button that generates new count values for all rows.

Currently the script page works like the following pseudo code:

```
While row1 {
 Select count1 from row1
 Update count1 in another table
 Select count2 from row1
 Update count2 in another table
}
```

The script takes about 30 seconds to complete, but I know it can be made faster by combining the queries somehow, however this is where I'm stuck.

This is the first SELECT query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(deals.Name)) AS CountOfAliases 
FROM deals 
WHERE MATCH(deals.Name) AGAINST ((SELECT CONCAT("'\"", Name, "\"'") FROM performers WHERE ID = 28327) IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

And this is the second:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CountOfDeals 
FROM deals 
WHERE MATCH(deals.Name) AGAINST ((SELECT CONCAT("'\"", Name, "\"'") FROM performers WHERE ID = 28327) IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

So my question is, instead of looping through each row in PHP, how do I get all the row ID's into the SQL and process them in a combined query?

Thanks,

Chris.

Comment: Forget about the PHP for now. Instead, and if you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: 30 seconds for fifty rows? That's pretty crazy. Have you indexed the appropriate columns you're searching on?